# Problem with includepdf invisible text in document

Tags: pdfpages

I am using includepdf to add some pdf pages to the appendix of my paper using the following command

```
\includepdf[width=\textwidth, pages={1},pagecommand=\section{Appendix}  {blablabla} ]{test.pdf}
```

The strange thing now is that I was looking for some text to check for errors and it found the word on the same page as the included PDF. So it seems like there is invisible text that I can select behind the included pdf. It seems to be text from another pdf that is included elsewhere or on another page of the pdf. Has anyone had the same problem?

Its actually not really bothering, but it would be strange if people start looking for the word and get to this page with no text.

Comment: What viewer are you using to look at the PDF?

Comment: You might not get much help with this question in the current form; can you make it more specific?  Can you create a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: Im using Foxit and Adobe, i can select the "invisible" text with both of them. 

Its kinda hard to get a workable example because Id need to include my pdf files.