# Invisible part introductions (\ctparttext{}) in classicthesis

Tags: pdftex, classicthesis

I have a strange problem.  In the resulting PDF of when my large (200+ pages) `classicthesis.sty` project is compiled, it works just nice, except that the part introductions are invisible.  The text is there, it can be selected (tried both Okular and Acroread) and copied, but not viewed.  It is invisible, or in the same color as the background.

I see that a similar question was asked here: [Problem with includepdf invisible text in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231145/problem-with-includepdf-invisible-text-in-document) and I have the same problems with providing a MWE.  Right now I have no idea what part of my enormous document actually causes this error, and am looking more for possible sources or ways to debug this further, so I can show the relevant parts of code that causes it.

My assumption was that there were some commonalities between problems causing text in the resulting pdf to be invisible, i.e., selectable.

Update 20150925; I have now resolved the issues by updating to the newest classicthesis.sty file (2015/01/01 as of now).  Then the problem disappeared.  Before I commented absolutely everything out, but the problem persisted.  I did not proceed to research what in the difference between the sty files made the improvement.

Comment: [A very simple and mechanical way to find the cause of problems](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.  Asking the question I assumed there would be some knowledge out there about what could cause the invisible text in resulting pdf behavior.

Comment: Note that ***creating an MWE is a debugging method***. Most often, you don't have a clue what is responsible. That is *precisely why* you create an MWE.

Comment: Note also that the problem is probably that you are using `classicthesis.sty`. I say this on the basis of induction: whenever people have mysterious issues and are using this, this is almost always responsible for the mysterious issues. The best thing is not to use it. Even if you solve this problem, the package will be a source of grief to you. It will haunt your dreams and insinuate itself into your nightmares. It will breed things which go bump in the night. And that's before you even get to your *viva*.

Comment: I have a huge thesis so I can't switch framework now.  Essentially it looks like I have to comment out sections until I find what's causing the error, as out-of-the-box it works nicely.

Comment: There are people here whose answer to any question about classicthesis is - don't use it. I'm surprised not to see such answers on reports for any other package whatsoever, for if there are issues it's best to avoid them rather than resolve. Hundreds of theses have been typeset using classicthesis, I'm sure you'll find your way too. How about commenting out all but one `\ctparttext`?

Comment: I think any problem in an enormous document would face the same problem. It's not a problem to find a MWE, if you start afresh the text will be visible. The problem is to find out whatever I added that made the text disappear, as I don't know exactly when this was.

Comment: Any special formatting in \ctparttext{}?  Copy the whole thesis and start deleting piece by piece until there's a change. Then start adding back.

Comment: It worked when I updated the .sty now. Without, even stripped down to bare minimum the text was invisible, so it must be something fundamental, but I didn't go into that.  Happy it works, finally'

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the classicthesis.sty file.
Black is erroneously defined as cmyk(0,0,0,0) which is transparent :)
Just change:

```
\definecolor{Black}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

to

```
\definecolor{Black}{cmyk}{75, 68, 67, 90}
```

and you're good to go

Comment: There's a % in front of that definition, so this won't help. '\ctparttext' worked well until some point, remember!